# About gridcontrol and column chooser

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a form that form has a gridcontrol then when I click column chooser I will add a any column that added column will remove on a gridcontrol when i close the form finally I do not want to lose that added column I hope I can explain what I want to do thank you for everything.

Comment: Are you looking to preserve the layout of the GridControl?

Have you looked at the Saving and Restoring Layouts documentation?

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument772

Comment: Yeap but I have no idea about that

Comment: for example I have a gridcontrol and that gridcontrol has two columns then I will create a column by click columns chooser while the program is running then I want to preserve the layout of the gridcontrol

Comment: Thank you Brendon I solved that

Comment: string filename = "C:\\Users\\WINDOWS 8\\Desktop\\deneme.xml";
        private void deneme_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridControl1.ForceInitialize();
            gridControl1.MainView.RestoreLayoutFromXml(filename);

        }

        private void deneme_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            gridControl1.MainView.SaveLayoutToXml(filename);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this example for customizing the columns :

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="CustomersDataSource"
    KeyFieldName="CustomerID" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ContactName" VisibleIndex="0" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" />
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CompanyName" VisibleIndex="1" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" />
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="City" VisibleIndex="2" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" />
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Region" Visible="false" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" />
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Country" VisibleIndex="3" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" />
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <PagerBar>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%">
                        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="Pager" runat="server" ReplacementType="Pager" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCustomizationWindow" runat="server" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/styles.css"
                            AutoPostBack="False" Text="Show/Hide Columns" Width="150px" ClientInstanceName="btnCustomizationWindow"
                            CssPostfix="Office2010Blue" SpriteCssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Office2010Blue/{0}/sprite.css">
                            <ClientSideEvents Click="btnCustomizationWindow_Click" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </PagerBar>
    </Templates>
    <Settings ShowGroupPanel="True" />
    <SettingsLoadingPanel Mode="ShowOnStatusBar" />
    <SettingsBehavior EnableCustomizationWindow="true" />
    <SettingsCookies CookiesID="CookiesV1" Enabled="True" StoreColumnsVisiblePosition="true"
        StoreColumnsWidth="true" StoreFiltering="False" StoreGroupingAndSorting="False"
        StorePaging="False" /><%--This will store the column position and visibility--%>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnCustomizationWindow_Click(s, e) {
            if(grid.IsCustomizationWindowVisible())
                grid.HideCustomizationWindow();
            else
                grid.ShowCustomizationWindow();
        }               
    </script>
```

Note:

If you wish to hide some columns for customization set the property :

```
ShowInCustomizationForm="false"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ruchi Rahul for your helps

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it worked for you :) Thank you @Mustafa